# CakePHP 3 : Auth->identify() always let a valid username in without checking the password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Auth->identify always let a valid username login without checking the password.  All I need is a valid username and I open the dashboard easily. When I changed the input password name in my login.ctp from password to password2 I can't login anymore. This is a strange problem I'm facing from yesterday but didn't figure out how to solve it.

This is the the app.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth',['loginRedirect'=>['controller'=>'Dashboard','action'=>'index'],
                                     'logoutRedirect'=>['controller'=>'Users',"action"=>"login"],
                                     'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                    ]);
```

This is my login view :

```
<form class="login-form" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo __("Username");?>" name="username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="<?php echo __("Password");?>" name="password"/>
    <button id="btn_login"><?php echo __("Login");?></button>
</form>
```

My Login function in UsersController :

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the mess may be here, the old developer create a table for users called app_members. There is no table in the database called users so he wrote the following :

In model/entity both user.php and appMember contain this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
class User (or AppMember) extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = ['*'=> true,'id' => false];
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
?>
```

And for the model/table/UsersTable.php he extend from the appMember :

```
<?php 
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
      $this->table('app_member');
    }
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
            ->notEmpty('role', 'A role is required');            
    }
}
```

---

Edit 1 :
app.php isAuthorized function :

```
public function isAuthorized($users)
    {
        if(isset($users))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the `app_member` contain a column named password, and do you see hashed values stored for passwords?

Comment: Yep, all seem fine for app_member and it has already a password field @cgTag

Comment: Can you please share the `function isAuthorized($user = null)` function from the controller.

Comment: @cgTag Please take a look in the topic above

Comment: oh wow! Yeah that's going to allow in **anyone**. lol

Comment: I'll post an answer to help you. One minute (having morning coffee).

Comment: So does any of the speculations I made in the comments apply? ("_Maybe there's more configuration applied somewhere else, maybe a custom authenticator is being used, maybe the OP only tested it with no password, not with a wrong password, and there actually is (a hash for) an empty password stored for that specific user (the `_setPassword()` method in the shown code doesn't prevent that, neither do the validation rules), etc..._"). If not, I'd suggest to do some debugging, that is set some breakpoints in the `FormAuthenticator` to figure if it's being reached, and where things go wrong.

Comment: @ndm I have a backup version (some days ago) of the project and it runs fine. I replaced the vendor folder and problem solved ! This is very strange ! It seems like a package problem.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time searching for the problem. I find that someone has modified the CakePHP src/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php and comment this :

```
/*if (!$hasher->check($password, $hashedPassword)) {
                return false;
            }*/
```

**PokerFace**